# Python - application and operation systems permission

Tags: python, pyinstaller

**Background:**
I am trying to turn my script into an end-user application that could be used independently on whether the end user has Python installed.

After long initial struggle I managed to create the app using PyInstaller module (I did not succeed with Py2App and Platypus even after spending hours googling and going through posts here on SO).

Although the final app created by PyInstaller works, it fails to create or modify any files.
E.g. a simple method:

```
   def save_xml(data):

        file_name = self.party_a_ICO_value.get()
        file_path = "ID_data/" + file_name + ".xml"
        f = open(file_path,"w")
        f.write(data)
        f.close()
```

that works perfectly well in the script stage, does not create the file once the script is transformed into an application.

What is even stranger is, that it does not return any (file permission or other) error, although no error handling is used in the code. It just does not create / modify the respective file and finishes without any error.

The above goes for Mac as well as Windows. I suppose the application is not permitted to create / modify files by the operating system. I presume the application would not only need to be created, but whole installation process (that presumably includes obtaining operating system permissions) would need to take place.

**Question:**
Is there a way how to turn a Python script into a functional application, that can create / modify files (at least in the directory in which the application is located)?

Thank you!

Comment: What is command you use to generate the exe? Do you use the `--onefile` flag?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes, I do use the --onefile flag.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are overcomplicating this. Instead you could use

```py
def save_xml(file_path, data):
    with open(file_path,"w") as f:
        f.write(data)
```

And to package the project use

```
pyinstaller example.py --onefile
```

Comment: For clarification I reccomend using [auto py to exe](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/). However for the certain question they are asking about pyinstaller